# react-scroll-to-bottom library, how to stick to bottom at initial render of chat screen?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll, chat

I am using an npm package [react-scroll-to-bottom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scroll-to-bottom) for the chat screen. Everything is working fine as I want but when a chat screen loads, it scrolls from top to bottom instead of starting from the bottom (last chat). I want it to stick to the bottom when the page loads.
In this [example](https://compulim.github.io/react-scroll-to-bottom/), the left side container is sticking to the bottom at page load, I want something like this.

```
import ScrollToBottom from 'react-scroll-to-bottom';

const Content = () => {


  return (
  <>
    <ScrollToBottom
      checkInterval={17}
      initialScrollBehavior="auto"
      atEnd={true}
      atBottom={true}
      sticky
      mode="bottom"
    >
     <div>Messages</div>
    </ScrollToBottom>
  
    <div>Input Section</div>
  </>
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not used this library but what you can do is you can create your own component as I did for the chat system in React.

Here is the code I am using **ScrollToBottom**:

```
const ScrollToBottom = () => {
    const elementRef = useRef();
    useEffect(() => elementRef.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth", block: "end", inline: "nearest" }));
    return <div ref={elementRef} />;
};
```

Place this component at the end of your chat component:

```
function ChatScreen() {
    return (
        <div className='chat-container'>
            {/* ... chat container ... */}
            <ScrollToBottom />
        </div>
    )
}
export default ChatScreen;
```

Comment: Someone else integrated this library into the project now it will be a mess and time taking to change things so I want to fix this with this library only.

Comment: I have tried this, but when I scroll up, it scrolls to bottom automatically after few seconds.

Comment: Can you share a code sample on codesandbox so I can take a look at that?